# ArcGIS for Servers 10.5 Output Parameter not properly set

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, python-toolbox

When publishing ArcGIS Python ToolBox, it still uses the Desktop Output folder.

The code below is coming from the toolbox.

```
class LandSimilarity(TargetingTool):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Land Similarity"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False
        self.parameters = [
            parameter("Input raster", "in_raster", "Raster Layer",
                      multiValue=True),
            parameter("Input point layer", "in_point", "Feature Layer"),
            parameter("Output extent", "out_extent", "Feature Layer",
                      parameterType='Optional'),
            parameter("R executable", "r_exe", "File"),
            parameter("Output Mahalanobis raster", "out_raster_mnobis",
                      'Raster Layer', direction='Output'),
            parameter("Output MESS raster", "out_raster_mess", 'Raster Layer',
                      direction='Output')
        ]

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        self.parameters[1].filter.list = ["Point"]  # Geometry type filter
        return self.parameters

   ....
   def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """ Execute functions to process input raster.
            Args:
                parameters: Parameters from the tool.
                messages: Internal validation messages
            Returns: Land suitability raster.
        """
        try:
            r_exe_path = parameters[3].valueAsText
            out_mnobis_ras = parameters[4].valueAsText.replace("\\",
                                                               "/")  # Get mahalanobis output
            out_mess_ras = parameters[5].valueAsText.replace("\\",
                                                             "/")  # Get mess output
            ras_temp_path = ntpath.dirname(
                out_mnobis_ras)  # Get path without file name
            ras_temp_path += "/Temp/"
            # Create temporary directory if it doesn't exist
            if not os.path.exists(ras_temp_path):
                os.makedirs(ras_temp_path)
            # Copy point layer to temporary directory
            in_fc_pt = parameters[1].valueAsText.replace("\\", "/")
            if os.path.isfile(in_fc_pt):
                in_fc_pt = self.copyDataset(ras_temp_path, in_fc_pt,
                                            in_fc_pt)  # Copy dataset from source to destination
            else:
                in_fc_pt = super(LandSimilarity, self).getLayerDataSource(
                    parameters[1])  # Get point layer data source
                in_fc_pt = self.copyDataset(ras_temp_path, in_fc_pt, in_fc_pt)

            # raster sample creation
            if parameters[2].value:
                in_fc = super(LandSimilarity, self).getInputFc(parameters[2])[
                    "in_fc"]
                extent = arcpy.Describe(
                    in_fc).extent  # Get feature class extent
                self.createValueSample(parameters, in_fc_pt, ras_temp_path,
                                       in_fc,
                                       extent)  # Create raster cell value sample
            else:
                self.createValueSample(parameters, in_fc_pt, ras_temp_path,
                                       in_fc=None,
                                       extent=None)  # Create raster cell value sample
            self.deleteTempFile(parameters,
                                ras_temp_path)  # Delete temporary files
            arcpy.AddMessage("Joining {0} to {1} \n".format(in_fc_pt,
                                                            ras_temp_path + "temp.dbf"))
            arcpy.JoinField_management(in_fc_pt, "FID",
                                       ras_temp_path + "temp.dbf", "OID",
                                       "")  # Join tables
            out_csv = ras_temp_path + "temp.csv"
            self.writeToCSV(in_fc_pt,
                            out_csv)  # Write feature class table to CSV file
            arcpy.management.Delete(in_fc_pt)  # Delete vector
            self.createRScript(parameters, ras_temp_path)  # Create R script
            self.runCommand(r_exe_path, ras_temp_path)  # Run R command
            self.asciiToRasterConversion(parameters,
                                         ras_temp_path)  # ASCII to raster conversion
            shutil.rmtree(ras_temp_path)  # Delete directory

            # Get raster and load to the current mxd
            out_ras = ""
            if arcpy.Exists(out_mnobis_ras) and arcpy.Exists(out_mess_ras):
                out_ras = [out_mnobis_ras, out_mess_ras]
            else:
                if arcpy.Exists(out_mnobis_ras):
                    out_ras = out_mnobis_ras
                elif arcpy.Exists(out_mess_ras):
                    out_ras = out_mess_ras
            super(LandSimilarity, self).loadOutput(
                out_ras)  # Load output to current MXD
            arcpy.RefreshCatalog(
                ntpath.dirname(out_mnobis_ras))  # Refresh folder
            return
        except Exception as ex:

            arcpy.AddMessage('ERROR: {0} \n'.format(ex))
```

Below is how to the toolbox looks like. 
[image]
It brings the following error message.

```
Submitted.
Executing...
Executing (Land Similarity): LandSimilarity E:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisuploads\services\targeting_tools\LandSimilarity.GPServer\if7853d60-27e6-40b8-a101-283848da59ea\uganda_rainfall_2011_Jan_to_Dec.tif "Feature Set" "Feature Set" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" D:\CIAT\data\man D:\CIAT\data\mess
Start Time: Sat Dec 09 07:22:17 2017
Executing (Land Similarity): LandSimilarity E:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisuploads\services\targeting_tools\LandSimilarity.GPServer\if7853d60-27e6-40b8-a101-283848da59ea\uganda_rainfall_2011_Jan_to_Dec.tif "Feature Set" "Feature Set" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" D:\CIAT\data\man D:\CIAT\data\mess
Start Time: Sat Dec 09 07:22:17 2017
Running script LandSimilarity...
ERROR: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: u'D:/'
Completed script LandSimilarity...
Succeeded at Sat Dec 09 07:22:20 2017 (Elapsed Time: 2.79 seconds)
Succeeded at Sat Dec 09 07:22:20 2017 (Elapsed Time: 3.35 seconds)
Invalid return value: D:\CIAT\data\man
Failed.
```

However, the Output Parameter is properly detected as shown below. 
Please note that there are two Raster Layer Outputs and a Map Services is created for the service. 
[image]

The toolbox runs fine in Desktop as shown in the result below. 
[image]
How could I make it publish the Raster Layer and remove the Desktop Output Parameters. 
Which are:

```
D:\CIAT\data\man D:\CIAT\data\mess
```

Comment: You cannot use local drives as output locations. Use scratchworkspace or scratchfolder as outlined in the documentation.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/managing-intermediate-data-in-models-and-scripts.htm and  http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/authoring-geoprocessing-tasks-with-python-scripts.htm

Comment: I didn't set those local output paths. What confused me is, I only used those paths for the execution I did on  ArcGIS desktop and I don't know how it took those parameters to the server. The server output path is set correctly and it is not editable.

Comment: Your output path is defined somewhere in your acript whether you did it or it is using defaults. You need to change it in the script, not the service interface. Also put the relevant portion of the code in the question.

Comment: The output path is not hard coded. It comes from the toolbox interface. I have added part of the toolbox code.

Comment: Your outpath and everything else  is a derivative of your  ras_temp_path, which is defined by your input parameter. So while not hard coded, it is still pointing to a local resource. This is wrong and will not work on the server. Define temp and output folders per the documentation using os.path.join( arcpy.env.scratchFolder, *)

Comment: A few more notes: your output parameter needs to be parameterType Derived. Users should not be able to define an output location, only the name, in which case parameters 4 and 5 will be string, and you will use os.path.join to define the actual output variable using the env.scratchFolder and outputName. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for finding the issue! Let me make those changes and report back.

Comment: @BenSNadler Could you post an answer so as my issue is now solved with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use local drives as output locations. Use scratchworkspace or scratchfolder as outlined in the documentation. [sharing-workflows](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/managing-intermediate-data-in-models-and-scripts.htm) and 
[publish  GP services](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/authoring-geoprocessing-tasks-with-python-scripts.htm)

You will need to do a few things:

- the outpath and everything else in the script is a derivative of your ras_temp_path, which is defined by your input parameter. So while not hard coded, all the working directories are still pointing to a local resource. This is will not work on the server. Define temp and output folders per the documentation using os.path.join( arcpy.env.scratchFolder, *)
- The output parameter needs to be parameterType Derived. Users should not be able to define an output location, only the name, in which case parameters 4 and 5 will be string, and you will use os.path.join to define the actual output variable using the env.scratchFolder and outputName.
- For a GP service you probably want to zip up both outputs into a single zipped folder and have one output for the users to download/unpack. This will improve the transfer speed.
- The outputs needs to be set like this:

  `arcpy.SetParameterAsText(4, final_ouput_path_in_the_server)`

  This enables the server to return an output to the client.